# How to kill a process running on oracle db server from putty?

Tags: sql, oracle, unix, sqlplus

I created one sql file in PuTTY and I kept it on running using below command:

```
sqlplus username/pwd@SSAR05 @exec_lmn_DELETE.sql > exec_lmn_DELETE_17102018.log &
```

I didn't note down the SPID of this, but now I want to kill this process.

How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

`ps -ef| grep "sqlplus"`

This should give you result like below:

```
mayankp  30927 22295  0 Oct09 pts/22   00:00:02 /home/mayankp/anaconda2/bin/python /home/mayankp/anaconda2/bin/ipython
```

where `30927` is the process id. Kill it like:

`kill -9 30927`

Answer (score 0):

I would say you must first go to the database and terminate the session there.

As there could be multiple SQL* Plus sessions in your current environment, you won't know which process you are terminating.

First identify the process ids from ps command.

```
knayak-/Users/knayak-$ps -ef | grep [s]qlplus
501 23750 23309   0 11:46AM ttys004    0:00.05 sqlplus
501 23445 23309   0 11:50AM ttys004    0:00.05 sqlplus
```

As you would see there are multiple sqlplus sessions, how do you identify which one belongs to you?

Connect to the relevant database session( ideally as a system / dba user )

```
SELECT s.username,
       s.sid,
       s.osuser,
       t.sql_id,
       sql_text,
       p.spid,  -- OS Process id of the Oracle process
       s.process . -- Client session process ID
FROM v$sqltext_with_newlines t JOIN
     v$session s
ON t.address = s.sql_address AND t.hash_value = s.sql_hash_value 
     JOIN v$process p ON p.addr = s.paddr
WHERE s.status = 'ACTIVE' AND s.username <> 'SYSTEM'
AND sql_text LIKE '%DELETE%' --This should correspond to your statements in the sql file.
AND s.process IN ( '<list of pids from the command>') --put the client pids here.
ORDER BY s.sid,
         t.piece;
```

Now, the client pid is different from the PID of the **Oracle process** that's running the job.

Firstly, kill the underlying Oracle process. you will see something like this when you run `ps` in the Oracle server and grep for the `spid` obtained from the query above.

```
oracle   63063     1 32 23:16 ?        00:11:12 oracleSSAR05 (LOCAL=NO)
```

If you cannot have access to Oracle's login, ask your DBA to terminate the session corresponding to this session.

Then kill the corresponding session if it exists connecting to db as a dba.

```
ALTER SYSTEM KILL SESSION '<sid>,<serial#>'; -- from the query above
```

Now, check to see if the client process is still running, it shouldn't be. Kill it finally if it's there.

Comment: Thanks for your help..is there any way to kill all the process which is currently running on a particular server?